# How to throw an exception as the output of a list comprehension?

Tags: python

I want to throw an exception if an item in a list isn't an integer through a list comprehension, how would this be done outside of an extra function?

Basically, is there a one-line approach to have an exception be called by the output of a list comprehension?

```
[raise Exception('Incorrect Data Type Present') for x in my_list if not isinstance(x,int)]
```

This, understandably, does not work.

Comment: No. This should just be a loop or an external function

Comment: You can't. `throw` is a statement (and there is no corresponding expression), and a list comprehension is an expression.

Comment: it can't, just wrap it in a function. Why don't you want to do that? It isn't clear why you are using a list comprehension ehre at all, since it doesn't seem like you actually want to create a list. So why not just a for-loop?

Comment: you can't `raise` more than once in a given invocation.

Comment: A list comprehension is not simply a one-line "shortcut" for a `for` loop; don't try to use it as such

Comment: like, it is totally unclear what the behavior you expect is

Comment: Thanks, I'll rework it.

Comment: Don't use comprehensions for side-effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a simple `if` statement, not a list comprehension.

```
if not all(isinstance(x, int) for x in my_list):
    raise Exception('Incorrect Data Type Present')
```

or equivalently,

```
if any(not isinstance(x, int) for x in my_list):
    raise Exception('Incorrect Data Type Present')
```

Based on the message, `Exception` should probably be `TypeError`.

You could also use a `for` loop in place of the generator expression consumed by `all`/`any`:

```
for x in my_list:
    if not isinstance(x, int):
        raise Exception('Incorrect Data Type Present')
```

Comment: the for-loop would probably be the best, then you could, for example, use `x` in the exception message

Comment: You could capture the offending `x` with an assignment expression, but yes, the `for` loop is probably more readable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so this?

`for i in my_list:
  if not isinstance(i,int):
    raise TypeError(i)`

edit: nvm they did it

Comment: @Dremloogic sure, except maybe with a useful error message

Comment: what worked for me was

`for i in i_list:
  if not i.isdigit():
    raise TypeError('Input only allows integers. \'%s\' was found.' % i)`